# Joining tables with sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables i wold like to join. One contains Customers, named "Customers". The other table "Customeraccounts". The tables have relation on Customer id. Like this.

```
Customers
1, john, Smith
```

---

```
CustomerAccounts
1, 1, 12345678
2, 1, 98765432
```

How can i join the tables to the output would be:

```
1, john, smith, 12345678, 98765432
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? You know you need to JOIN, did you look at the documentation for the JOIN clause?

Comment: @Oded: A JOIN would not be enough to do this. @espen: Why do you want to create this kind of output in SQL? That's something for the application layer, not for the database.

Comment: i've tried all the join clauses i could find, i thought i wolud get it right with the inner join. But i get 
john, smith, 12345678
john, smith, 98765432

My goal is to get all the accounts for a customer in one line.

Comment: im trying to get an export tom excel with dts export wizard

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer RIGHT OUTER JOIN CustomerAccounts
ON Customer.customer_id=CustomerAccounts.customer_id;
```

Comment: If you want it in a single row then you will have to apply some logic as well, apart from SQL.

Comment: select the code block and press <ctrl>+K to make it look like source code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would work for you:

```
SELECT Customers.Id, 
       Customers.LastName, 
       Customers.FirstName,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + CustomerAccounts.Number
              FROM CustomerAccounts
              WHERE CustomerAccounts.CustomerId = Customers.Id
         FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') 
       AS AllCustomerAccounts   
FROM Customers
```

Comment: that one almost did the trick. that puts the acounts in to one column.

Comment: would it be posible to split the string in to one column each. Like |Account 1| acount 2| account 3 |?

Comment: hm, maybe but i don't know how :-(

Answer (score 1):

In **MySQL** you can do

```
SELECT 
  Cust.ID
  , Cust.Forname
  , Cust.Name
  , GROUP_CONCAT(Acc.Number) as AccNumber
FROM CustomerAccount Acc 
INNER JOIN Customers Cust ON Acc.ID_Customer = Cust.ID 
GROUP BY Cust.id
```

In **SQL server** you'll have to tweak it a bit and do:

```
SELECT     
  Cust.ID,
  , Cust.Forname  
  , Cust.Name
  , AccNumber = replace                           
     ((SELECT A2.number AS [data()]                               
       FROM CustomerAccount A2 
       INNER JOIN Customers C2 ON A2.ID_Customer = C2.ID
       WHERE Cust.id = C2.id  
       ORDER BY A2.number FOR xml path('')), ' ', REQUIRED SEPERATOR) 
FROM CustomerAccount Acc  
INNER JOIN Customers Cust ON Acc.ID_Customer = Cust.ID 
GROUP BY Cust.id, cust.Forname, cust.Name
```

See also this question: [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select
Acc.ID,
Cust.Forname,
Cust.Name,
Acc.Number

From CustomerAccount Acc
Inner Join Customers Cust
On Acc.ID_CUstomer = Cust.ID
```

I assume your column are

CustomerAccount
ID|ID_Customer|Number

Customers
ID|ForName|Name

I think It'll work